# Dynamic subpartition creation to a partitioned table with data

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, dynamic-programming

I have a table like below

```
Create table t1( 
X number,
Y number ,
Z varchar,
Createdatetime date);
Partition by range (createdatetime) interval (numtodsinterval(3,day));
```

Above table has 5 billion data already partitioned by createdatetime

Now the requirement is to add new column

There may be multiple entries for x,y combo. So the new column must have Y for recent   x,y combo (based on creatdatetime) and N for old entries.

I created a column and populated data.

Now I need to subpartition the above range partition
.

Subpartition by list using new column
There will be two sub partitions Y,N based on new column under each date range partitions. How to achieve this dynamically. I tried writing a procedure which loops through the partitions and execute immediate alter table modify partition add subpartition.  But I'm getting invalid partition name error .

Any other alternative approaches are also welcome

Comment: Please show us the code you tried.

Comment: Begin
For a in (select partition_name from all_tab_partitions where table_name='t1')
Loop
Execute immediate 'alter table t1 modify partition '||a.partition||' add subpartition by list (newcol);
End loop;
End;

Comment: I tried this code and got invalid partition name error .

Comment: Please edit your question for such additional information instead of a comment.